# SQL order by highest to lowest in one table referencing another table in an UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Hey all I have the following tables that need in order to get data from one that matches the other and have it from highest to lowest depending on the int of TempVersion.

```
UPDATE
    net_Users
SET
    net_Users.DefaultId = b.TId
FROM
    (SELECT 
        TOP 1 IndivId, 
        TId 
     FROM 
        UTeams 
     WHERE 
        UTeams.[Active] = 1 
     ORDER BY 
        TempVersion DESC
    ) AS b
WHERE
    net_Users.IndivId = b.IndivId
```

In the above I am trying to order from the highest **TempVersion** to the lowest.

The query above seems to just update 1 of those records with the **TempVersion** and stop there. I am needing it to loop to find all associated users with the same **IndivId** matching.

Anyone able to help me out with this?

**sample data**

net_Users:

```
name    | DefaultId | IndivId | etc...
--------+-----------+---------+-------
Bob     |           | 87      | etc...
Jan     |           | 231     | etc...
Luke    |           | 8       | etc...
```

UTeams:

```
IndivId | TempVersion | etc...
--------+-------------+-------
8       | 44          | etc...
17      | 18          | etc...
8       | 51          | etc...
8       | 2           | etc...
7       | 22          | etc...
8       | 125         | etc...
87      | 10          | etc...
14      | 88          | etc...
8       | 5           | etc...
15      | 54          | etc...
65      | 11          | etc...
87      | 15          | etc...
39      | 104         | etc...
```

And the output I would be needing is (going to choose IndivId 8):

In net_users:

```
Name | DefaultId | IndivId | etc...
-----+-----------+---------+-------
Luke | 125       | 8       | etc...
Luke | 51        | 8       | etc...
Luke | 44        | 8       | etc...
Luke | 5         | 8       | etc...
Luke | 2         | 8       | etc...
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: What is the purpose of TOP 1 in your code?

Comment: Updated the OP with example.

Comment: Where did `tid` and `[active]` go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you were trying to do:

```
update net_Users
  set net_Users.DefaultId = coalesce((
    select top 1 TId
    from UTeams
    where UTeams.[Active] = 1
      and net_Users.IndivId = UTeams.IndivId
    order by u.TempVersion desc
    )
    ,net_Users.DefaultId
    )
```

another way using [**`cross apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
update n
  set DefaultId = coalesce(x.Tid,n.DefaultId)
from net_Users as n
cross apply (
  select top 1 TId
  from UTeams as u
  where u.[Active] = 1
    and n.IndivId = u.IndivId
  order by u.TempVersion desc
) as x
```

another way to do that with a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) and [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
with cte as (
  select 
    n.IndivId
  , n.DefaultId
  , u.Tid
  , rn = row_number() over (
      partition by n.IndivId 
      order by TempVersion desc
      )
  from net_users as n
    inner join UTeams as u
      on n.IndivId = u.IndivId
  where u.[Active]=1
)
update cte
set DefaultId = Tid
where rn = 1
```